# SVG files have same width and no viewbox but both look different sizes

Tags: svg

These 2 SVG images have the same widths, but the XBox logo, and the Amazon logo, look completely different width sizes when viewed on screen. Why is this?

**Xbox:**

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="100px"><path d="M61.1,15.4l-3.7-5-3.6,5H52.3l4.4-6L52.7,4h1.5l3.2,4.4L60.7,4h1.5l-4,5.4,4.4,6Zm-28.4,0-4.4-6,4-5.4H30.8L27.5,8.4,24.3,4H22.8l4,5.4-4.4,6h1.5l3.6-5,3.7,5Z" transform="translate(0)" style="fill:#0f7c10"/><path d="M41,9.8l-.7-.5a2.6,2.6,0,0,0,1.4-2.2c0-.8-.3-3.1-3.8-3.1H33.3V8.9H31.8L30.9,10h2.4v5.4h4.6c2.6,0,4.1-1.3,4.1-3.4a2.7,2.7,0,0,0-1-2.2M34.6,5.1h3.3c1,0,2.5.3,2.5,1.9s-.9,1.9-2.5,1.9H34.6Zm3.3,9.1H34.6V10h3.3c1.3,0,2.8.4,2.8,2s-1.7,2.2-2.8,2.2M48,3.7c-3.2,0-5.4,2.4-5.4,6s2.2,5.9,5.4,5.9,5.5-2.4,5.5-5.9-2.3-6-5.5-6m0,10.7c-2.4,0-4.1-1.9-4.1-4.7S45.6,4.9,48,4.9s4.2,2,4.2,4.8-1.7,4.7-4.2,4.7M2.8,2.7h0A9.7,9.7,0,0,0,0,9.5a10.1,10.1,0,0,0,1.9,5.8H2C1.3,13,5,7.6,6.9,5.3h0C3.7,2,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.7m13.4,0h0A9.7,9.7,0,0,1,19,9.5a10.1,10.1,0,0,1-1.9,5.8H17c.7-2.2-3-7.6-4.9-9.9h0c3.2-3.2,4.1-2.4,4.1-2.5M9.5,0a9.4,9.4,0,0,1,5,1.4h0c0,.1,0,.1-.1.1-1.8-.4-4.6,1.1-4.9,1.3h0C8.8,2.4,6.2,1,4.6,1.5a.1.1,0,0,1-.1-.1h0A9.4,9.4,0,0,1,9.5,0m0,7.6h0c2.9,2.2,7.8,7.6,6.3,9.1h0a9.8,9.8,0,0,1-12.6,0h0C1.8,15.2,6.6,9.8,9.5,7.6h0" transform="translate(0)" style="fill:#0f7c10"/></svg>
```

**Amazon**

```
<svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="100px"><path d="M198.6 75.5c-18.6 13.7-45.5 21-68.8 21a124.2 124.2 0 0 1-84-32.1c-1.7-1.5-.2-3.7 1.9-2.5 23.9 14 53.5 22.3 84.1 22.3a165.9 165.9 0 0 0 64.1-13.1c3.2-1.3 5.8 2.1 2.7 4.4z" fill="#f49800" fill-rule="evenodd"/><path d="M206.4 66.6c-2.4-3-15.7-1.4-21.7-.7-1.9.2-2.1-1.4-.5-2.5 10.7-7.5 28.1-5.3 30.1-2.8s-.5 20-10.5 28.3c-1.5 1.3-3 .6-2.3-1.1 2.2-5.6 7.3-18.1 4.9-21.2z" fill="#f49800" fill-rule="evenodd"/><path d="M185.1 10.5V3.3a1.8 1.8 0 0 1 1.8-1.9h32.6a1.9 1.9 0 0 1 1.9 1.9v6.2c0 1-.9 2.4-2.5 4.6l-16.8 24.1c6.2-.2 12.8.8 18.5 4a3.2 3.2 0 0 1 1.8 2.8v7.7a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-2.4 1.7 37.8 37.8 0 0 0-34.5.1c-1.1.6-2.3-.6-2.3-1.7v-7.4a8.6 8.6 0 0 1 1.2-5l19.6-28h-17a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.9-1.9zM66.3 55.9h-10a1.7 1.7 0 0 1-1.7-1.6V3.4a1.8 1.8 0 0 1 1.9-1.8h9.2a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 1.8 1.7v6.6h.2c2.4-6.4 7-9.4 13.1-9.4s10 3 12.8 9.4a14.7 14.7 0 0 1 25.2-3.8c3.1 4.2 2.5 10.4 2.5 15.9v32.1a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.8h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.8v-27c0-2.1.2-7.4-.3-9.5s-3-4.4-5.8-4.4a6.7 6.7 0 0 0-6 4.2c-1 2.6-.9 6.9-.9 9.7v27a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.9 1.8h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.8v-27c0-5.6.9-14-6.1-14s-6.8 8.2-6.8 14v27a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.8zM249.5 10.9c-7.3 0-7.8 9.9-7.8 16.1s0 19.5 7.7 19.5 8.1-10.7 8.1-17.2c0-4.3-.2-9.4-1.5-13.5s-3.3-4.9-6.5-4.9zM249.4.5c14.7 0 22.7 12.6 22.7 28.7S263.3 57 249.4 57s-22.3-12.6-22.3-28.4S235.1.5 249.4.5zM291.2 55.9h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.8V3.2a1.9 1.9 0 0 1 1.9-1.6h9.2a1.8 1.8 0 0 1 1.8 1.4v7.8h.1c2.8-7 6.7-10.3 13.5-10.3 4.5 0 8.8 1.6 11.6 6s2.6 10.9 2.6 15.8v32a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.6h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.6V26.7c0-5.5.6-13.7-6.2-13.7a6.4 6.4 0 0 0-5.7 4.1c-1.4 3.1-1.6 6.2-1.6 9.6v27.4a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.8zM169.1 55.8a2 2 0 0 1-2.3.2c-3.3-2.7-3.9-4-5.7-6.6-5.5 5.6-9.3 7.2-16.4 7.2s-14.8-5.1-14.8-15.4A16.8 16.8 0 0 1 140.5 25c5.4-2.4 12.9-2.8 18.6-3.4v-1.3c0-2.4.2-5.2-1.2-7.2a6.7 6.7 0 0 0-5.6-2.6c-3.7 0-7.1 1.9-7.9 6a2.1 2.1 0 0 1-1.7 1.8l-9.6-1.1a1.6 1.6 0 0 1-1.5-2C133.8 3.5 144.3 0 153.7 0c4.9 0 11.2 1.3 15 4.9S173 15.4 173 22v15.4c0 4.7 2 6.7 3.8 9.2a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-.1 2.6l-7.6 6.6zm-10-24.2c0 3.9.1 7.1-1.8 10.6s-4.1 4.5-6.9 4.5-6-2.9-6-7.2c0-8.5 7.5-10 14.7-10v2.1zM39.2 55.8a2 2 0 0 1-2.3.2c-3.3-2.7-3.9-4-5.7-6.6-5.5 5.6-9.3 7.2-16.4 7.2S0 51.5 0 41.2A16.8 16.8 0 0 1 10.6 25c5.3-2.4 12.9-2.8 18.6-3.4v-1.3c0-2.4.2-5.2-1.2-7.2a6.7 6.7 0 0 0-5.6-2.6c-3.7 0-7.1 1.9-7.9 6a2.2 2.2 0 0 1-1.8 1.8l-9.6-1.1a1.6 1.6 0 0 1-1.4-2C3.9 3.5 14.4 0 23.8 0c4.8 0 11.2 1.3 15 4.9s4.3 10.5 4.3 17.1v15.4c0 4.7 1.9 6.7 3.7 9.2.7.9.8 2 0 2.6l-7.6 6.6zm-10-24.2c0 3.9.1 7.1-1.9 10.6a8 8 0 0 1-6.8 4.5c-3.8 0-6-2.9-6-7.2 0-8.5 7.5-10 14.7-10v2.1z" fill="#12100b" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Why is this?

Comment: Why downvote this is a genuine question, easy to understand, and XML is code?

Comment: not me buddy, not me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully inspect, you realize they have the same boundingClientRect, however it is the path elements that are different:

```
<path d="M41,9.8l-.7-.5a2.6,2.6,0,0,0,1.4-2.2c0-.8-.3-3.1-3.8-3.1H33.3V8.9H31.8L30.9,10h2.4v5.4h4.6c2.6,0,4.1-1.3,4.1-3.4a2.7,2.7,0,0,0-1-2.2M34.6,5.1h3.3c1,0,2.5.3,2.5,1.9s-.9,1.9-2.5,1.9H34.6Zm3.3,9.1H34.6V10h3.3c1.3,0,2.8.4,2.8,2s-1.7,2.2-2.8,2.2M48,3.7c-3.2,0-5.4,2.4-5.4,6s2.2,5.9,5.4,5.9,5.5-2.4,5.5-5.9-2.3-6-5.5-6m0,10.7c-2.4,0-4.1-1.9-4.1-4.7S45.6,4.9,48,4.9s4.2,2,4.2,4.8-1.7,4.7-4.2,4.7M2.8,2.7h0A9.7,9.7,0,0,0,0,9.5a10.1,10.1,0,0,0,1.9,5.8H2C1.3,13,5,7.6,6.9,5.3h0C3.7,2,2.8,2.8,2.8,2.7m13.4,0h0A9.7,9.7,0,0,1,19,9.5a10.1,10.1,0,0,1-1.9,5.8H17c.7-2.2-3-7.6-4.9-9.9h0c3.2-3.2,4.1-2.4,4.1-2.5M9.5,0a9.4,9.4,0,0,1,5,1.4h0c0,.1,0,.1-.1.1-1.8-.4-4.6,1.1-4.9,1.3h0C8.8,2.4,6.2,1,4.6,1.5a.1.1,0,0,1-.1-.1h0A9.4,9.4,0,0,1,9.5,0m0,7.6h0c2.9,2.2,7.8,7.6,6.3,9.1h0a9.8,9.8,0,0,1-12.6,0h0C1.8,15.2,6.6,9.8,9.5,7.6h0" transform="translate(0)" style="fill:#0f7c10"></path>
```

way smaller than:

```
<path d="M185.1 10.5V3.3a1.8 1.8 0 0 1 1.8-1.9h32.6a1.9 1.9 0 0 1 1.9 1.9v6.2c0 1-.9 2.4-2.5 4.6l-16.8 24.1c6.2-.2 12.8.8 18.5 4a3.2 3.2 0 0 1 1.8 2.8v7.7a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-2.4 1.7 37.8 37.8 0 0 0-34.5.1c-1.1.6-2.3-.6-2.3-1.7v-7.4a8.6 8.6 0 0 1 1.2-5l19.6-28h-17a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.9-1.9zM66.3 55.9h-10a1.7 1.7 0 0 1-1.7-1.6V3.4a1.8 1.8 0 0 1 1.9-1.8h9.2a1.7 1.7 0 0 1 1.8 1.7v6.6h.2c2.4-6.4 7-9.4 13.1-9.4s10 3 12.8 9.4a14.7 14.7 0 0 1 25.2-3.8c3.1 4.2 2.5 10.4 2.5 15.9v32.1a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.8h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.8v-27c0-2.1.2-7.4-.3-9.5s-3-4.4-5.8-4.4a6.7 6.7 0 0 0-6 4.2c-1 2.6-.9 6.9-.9 9.7v27a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.9 1.8h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.8v-27c0-5.6.9-14-6.1-14s-6.8 8.2-6.8 14v27a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.8zM249.5 10.9c-7.3 0-7.8 9.9-7.8 16.1s0 19.5 7.7 19.5 8.1-10.7 8.1-17.2c0-4.3-.2-9.4-1.5-13.5s-3.3-4.9-6.5-4.9zM249.4.5c14.7 0 22.7 12.6 22.7 28.7S263.3 57 249.4 57s-22.3-12.6-22.3-28.4S235.1.5 249.4.5zM291.2 55.9h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.8V3.2a1.9 1.9 0 0 1 1.9-1.6h9.2a1.8 1.8 0 0 1 1.8 1.4v7.8h.1c2.8-7 6.7-10.3 13.5-10.3 4.5 0 8.8 1.6 11.6 6s2.6 10.9 2.6 15.8v32a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.6h-9.9a1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.8-1.6V26.7c0-5.5.6-13.7-6.2-13.7a6.4 6.4 0 0 0-5.7 4.1c-1.4 3.1-1.6 6.2-1.6 9.6v27.4a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-1.9 1.8zM169.1 55.8a2 2 0 0 1-2.3.2c-3.3-2.7-3.9-4-5.7-6.6-5.5 5.6-9.3 7.2-16.4 7.2s-14.8-5.1-14.8-15.4A16.8 16.8 0 0 1 140.5 25c5.4-2.4 12.9-2.8 18.6-3.4v-1.3c0-2.4.2-5.2-1.2-7.2a6.7 6.7 0 0 0-5.6-2.6c-3.7 0-7.1 1.9-7.9 6a2.1 2.1 0 0 1-1.7 1.8l-9.6-1.1a1.6 1.6 0 0 1-1.5-2C133.8 3.5 144.3 0 153.7 0c4.9 0 11.2 1.3 15 4.9S173 15.4 173 22v15.4c0 4.7 2 6.7 3.8 9.2a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-.1 2.6l-7.6 6.6zm-10-24.2c0 3.9.1 7.1-1.8 10.6s-4.1 4.5-6.9 4.5-6-2.9-6-7.2c0-8.5 7.5-10 14.7-10v2.1zM39.2 55.8a2 2 0 0 1-2.3.2c-3.3-2.7-3.9-4-5.7-6.6-5.5 5.6-9.3 7.2-16.4 7.2S0 51.5 0 41.2A16.8 16.8 0 0 1 10.6 25c5.3-2.4 12.9-2.8 18.6-3.4v-1.3c0-2.4.2-5.2-1.2-7.2a6.7 6.7 0 0 0-5.6-2.6c-3.7 0-7.1 1.9-7.9 6a2.2 2.2 0 0 1-1.8 1.8l-9.6-1.1a1.6 1.6 0 0 1-1.4-2C3.9 3.5 14.4 0 23.8 0c4.8 0 11.2 1.3 15 4.9s4.3 10.5 4.3 17.1v15.4c0 4.7 1.9 6.7 3.7 9.2.7.9.8 2 0 2.6l-7.6 6.6zm-10-24.2c0 3.9.1 7.1-1.9 10.6a8 8 0 0 1-6.8 4.5c-3.8 0-6-2.9-6-7.2 0-8.5 7.5-10 14.7-10v2.1z" fill="#12100b" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/4d968ta0/1/

SOLUTION:

readjust the viewBox attribute on the Xbox figure so that the paths fills it nicely, you might not get the scale perfect so to make sure disable preserveAspectRatio:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

Lastly, get rid of width and height attributes and define them in the css, like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/4d968ta0/5/

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware of this. Think I'm going to grab SVG Essentials. So, what would I have to do in order to have these images the same size/proportion?

Comment: Wait a sec, I'm trying to do that

Comment: There you go, see the fiddle

Comment: How did you get those values? Is there a formula or just messing around until it looks right?

Comment: You can call getBBox on the path elements to see the boundaries. And then you can combine the rectangles to find the minimum union rectangle etc. Then set the viewBox to that rectangle, you will need js for this though, I did it by hand.

Comment: Solved it another way, see my answer. Can you see any issues with it? It feels like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out. Finally! There's a simple way to do this. Like so:

```
<svg id="xbox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 60.7"><title>xbox</title><rect width="200" height="60.68" style="fill:none"/><path d="M195.2,49.2l-11.8-16-11.5,16h-4.8L181.2,30,168.4,12.8h4.8l10.2,14,10.5-14h4.8L185.9,30,200,49.2Zm-90.7,0L90.4,30l12.8-17.2H98.4l-10.5,14-10.3-14H72.8L85.6,30l-14,19.2h4.8l11.5-16,11.8,16Z" style="fill:#0f7c10"/><path d="M131,31.3l-2.2-1.6a8.2,8.2,0,0,0,4.4-7c0-2.6-.9-9.9-12.1-9.9H106.4V28.4h-4.8l-2.9,3.5h7.7V49.2h14.7c8.3,0,13.1-4.2,13.1-10.9a8.6,8.6,0,0,0-3.2-7m-20.5-15h10.6c3.2,0,8,1,8,6.1s-2.9,6-8,6H110.5Zm10.6,29.1H110.5V31.9h10.6c4.1,0,8.9,1.3,8.9,6.4s-5.4,7.1-8.9,7.1m32.3-33.6c-10.3,0-17.3,7.7-17.3,19.2s7,18.8,17.3,18.8,17.5-7.6,17.5-18.8-7.3-19.2-17.5-19.2m0,34.2c-7.7,0-13.1-6.1-13.1-15s5.4-15.3,13.1-15.3S166.8,22,166.8,31s-5.5,15-13.4,15M8.9,8.6h0A31,31,0,0,0,0,30.4,32.5,32.5,0,0,0,6.1,48.9h.3C4.2,41.5,16,24.3,22,16.9h0C11.8,6.4,8.9,8.9,8.9,8.6m42.9,0h0a31,31,0,0,1,8.9,21.8,32.5,32.5,0,0,1-6.1,18.5h-.3c2.2-7-9.6-24.3-15.6-31.6h0C48.9,7,51.8,9.6,51.8,9.3M30.4,0A29.9,29.9,0,0,1,46.3,4.5h0c0,.3,0,.3-.3.3C40.3,3.5,31.3,8.3,30.4,8.9h0C28.1,7.7,19.8,3.2,14.7,4.8a.3.3,0,0,1-.3-.3h0A30,30,0,0,1,30.4,0m0,24.3h0c9.2,7,24.9,24.3,20.1,29.1h0a31.5,31.5,0,0,1-40.3,0h0C5.8,48.6,21.1,31.3,30.4,24.3h0" style="fill:#0f7c10"/></svg>
```

The problem was when you export an image from Illustrator (as many do) the artboard is not included in the exported SVG. The paths have nothing to base their calculations on.

In my case the max height for my images was `100px` and I needed to base the CSS styles for these images based on their width and height. In CSS I use `vw` units, or just plain old `100%` if the SVG is to fill block space. This scales nicely. That way you haven't go to mess about setting the width and height in CSS to ensure it displays correctly.

I went through each logo and set the height to `100px` and let the width auto calculate based on the aspect ratio. I then fit the artboard to the logo to remove any unused space.

I selected a rectangle and turned fill and stroke off and I ensured it was the exact same size as the artboard. Place this blank object at the back. Now when you export the path will have a base to work the calculations on.

To do this in code it appears you can wrap the paths in a `rect` and set it's width and height, and then you can set the `viewBox` to the same (keep aspect ratios the same). As shown in the example above. I haven't actually tested this but I will test and update.

Comment: This is identical, the default value for preserveAspectRatio is "xMidYMid". Browser automatically scales anyway when you set only width or height provided that viewBox is set. The only reason I set preserveAspectRatio none is to make sure,no part of svg gets out of bounds. And based on what software you are working on this can happen. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/4d968ta0/11/

Comment: Ha! Today I learned. Thank you for your input and helping to understand this.